# How to use fibonacci to calculate the various ways to domino tile?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

(This may seem like this was already answered, but I am looking something more specific.) For schoolwork I need to write a method that calculates the different ways a rectangle can be tiled by a domino tile of 2*1. From what I can see, it would be the fibonacci numbers of the area. I wrote code that compiled in the compiler, but not sure it really makes sense and am clueless where to go from here. How would I be able to implement this better?

```
public static int domino(int n, int m) // the method signature is what I must use according the hw instructions
{
int area =  n*m; // calculating the area of the passed in rectangle
int dominoes = area/2; // calculating how many dominos will be needed to cover the area
if (dominoes<=2) { // because fib 1 equals 1 and fib 2 equals 1
    return 1;
} //also the stopping point
else {return domino(dominoes-1, 0) + domino(dominoes-2, 0);}
}
```

I do not need to worry about efficiency for this homework.

Comment: I think you need to describe your need a bit more as I'm having hard time understanding your use case.

Comment: What do you mean about use case? I am trying to write a proper recursive method that works, but stuck as to how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correctly computing the Fibonacci numbers using your recursive calls. You are executing:

> ```
> else {return domino(dominoes-1, 0) + domino(dominoes-2, 0);}
> ```

So essentially, in the first recursive call `n == (dominoes - 1)` and `m == 0`. This means that calculating the area always results in 0, as multiplying anything by 0 equals 0.

My advice would be to use an extra Fibonacci function like so:

```
public static int domino(int n, int m) {
    // return the fibonacci number of the number of dominoes in the given rectangle
    return fib((n * m) / 2);
}

public static int fib(int n) {
    if(n <= 2)
        // seed values of the fibonacci sequence
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was thinking. But if I understand the instructions correctly, I cannot use a helper method for the homework.

Comment: Well, you could also easily implement fibonacci iteratively instead of recursively. Then you would not need a helper functions. Or, you could use the function you already have, but replace the `0` in the call I mentioned above and replace it with something else, that does not result in a 0 area. Hint: By what can we multiply a number and yield the same number as a result?

Comment: The homework is specifically to practice recursion. But that hint is great! I knew there was something off with my method and this is what I need.